# How to upgrade libxml to a specific version in Linux for php?

Tags: php, libxml2

I need to upgrade the libxml library without recompiling php. Tried the following steps:

1. Download the required version from `ftp://xmlsoft.org/libxml2/` (.tar.gz file)
2. Extracted the `.tar.gz` file and "cd" command to enter to that folder (eg: libxml2-2.9.5)
3. Then executed following commands

   ```
   ./configure
   make
   sudo make install
   ```

All success, but still the `php -I | grep libxml` is showing the old version only. Please help.

Comment: If you're on Linux and libxml2 was installed in `/usr/local` (which should be the default location if you don't supply a `--prefix` to `configure`), try to run `sudo ldconfig` after the installation.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing between the Library and the PHP Extension, PHP Extension is just a wrapper for the library to be able to use it in your PHP code.

So compiling a library does not means that you can use it as an extension for PHP, You will still need to **compile** a new version from the *extension* and use the new version of the library with it.

To upgrade your extension to a specific library version often you will need to compile it from source, the problem with libxml is that it is bundled with PHP by default.

> The optional --with-libxml-dir directive is used to specify the
>   location of libxml on the system that PHP is being compiled on,
>   otherwise only the default locations are scanned.

So you may need to recompile a new PHP version from source, and pass the new compiled bin for the new version of libxml to it just like what had been mentioned in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/libxml.installation.php):-

```
./configure .... --with-libxml-dir=/path/to/libxml
```

---

Instead of recompiling a new version of PHP and lose all of your current extensions configurations, you may try only recompiling [xml extension](https://github.com/php/php-src/tree/master/ext/libxml) from source and override the current extension as follows:

clone a new version of PHP:

```
git clone git@github.com:php/php-src.git
cd php-src/ext/libxml
git checkout YOUR_INSTALLED_PHP_VERSION
phpize
./configure --with-libxml-dir=/path/to/libxml
make
make install
```

Comment: Thanks hassan for clarifying it. If that's the case, I believe I have to download the PHP source to /user/local/src location, extract it and execute the ./configure command from that new location. Please correct me if I am wrong. Also, should I provide all the existing library details when I execute the ./configure command for recompiling php? Is there any command for listing all those list (if needed)?

Comment: no, you do not need to put the whole source code in `/usr/local/sr/` to compile PHP from source [checkout this](http://www.phpinternalsbook.com/php7/build_system/building_php.html) , also yes, you will need to reconfigure all of the current libraries.

Comment: This answer is partly wrong. It is possible to only recompile libxml2 and make PHP use the new version with a mechanism like `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: @nwellnhof does this differ from the second part of the answer? compiling libxml from source?

Comment: Thanks @hassan for all your help. I believe the above mentioned command is using for recompiling php with new libxml version. But, I think still we have to provide the current list of libraries (which were installed already in the system) when compiling php with ./configure command. Otherwise we will loose them. Is that correct? If that is the case, is there any way to find out the list of libraries that are installed already in the system or how we can provide them when recompiling php? Please advise.

Comment: @007 The second solution is used to only compile the xml library in PHP, and will not recompile PHP from scratch, also to get the all installed PHP modules you can make a use of `php -m` command.

Comment: Thanks a lot @hassan.

When I check, I could not see a folder location like "php-src/tree/master/ext/libxml"
But, I found another location "php-src/ext/libxml". So I used "cd /php-src/ext/libxml".
Then I checkout the PHP version PHP-7.1.17 and executed phpsize command from there.
But it is showing the error "Cannot find config.m4. 
Make sure that you run '/usr/local/bin/phpize' in the top level source directory of the module".

I can see config0.m4 file in that folder but not config.m4.
Any idea?

Comment: @007 try to rename that file `config0.m4` to `config.m4`